# Use React Fragment with TypeScript on a React-Native project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I just upgraded React to 16.2.0 on my React-Native project to use the new Fragment syntax.

I have a component which returns something like this now:

```
return (
  <>
    <View>...</View>
    <View>...</View>
  </>
);
```

TypeScript doesn't complain about the syntax which is great, however I get an error when I try to run this code:

```
Bundling `index.js`  [development, non-minified]  45.8% (1078/1593), failed.
error: bundling failed: SyntaxError in /Users/alexmngn/Workspace/MyProject/MyComponent.tsx: /Users/alexmngn/Workspace/MyProject/MyComponent.tsx: Unexpected token (68:17)
> 68 |         return (<>
     |                  ^
```

It doesn't seem to compile the fragment syntax back to ES5.

And when I try to use `React.Fragment` instead I get a TypeScript error:

```
/Users/alexmngn/Workspace/MyProject/MyComponent.tsx(1,28): error TS2305: 
Module '"/Users/alexmngn/Workspace/MyProject/node_modules/@types/react/index"' 
has no exported member 'Fragment'.
```

And the app doesn't run and throw an error as well `Invariant Violation`

I use the latest stable versions of all packages:

- React: 16.2.0
- React-Native: 0.51.0
- TypeScript: 2.6.2
- @types/react: 16.0.31
- @types/react-native: 0.51.4

Is there anything specific I need to do to make it working with React-Native? To compile to ES5? Or even to be able to use React.Fragment without Typescript complaining? Seems like there is a type `ReactFragment` in the definition of the types but still get this error.

Thanks

Comment: I guess you should follow this issue https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/20249. As one of the comment suggest, there is workaround for now https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/20249#issuecomment-348384719

Comment: @EduardJacko  write that as the answer.